# web2py create URL args with @ character

Tags: escaping, web2py

I want to create a url on a web2py-generated page that looks like

```
http://example.com/app/controller/@an-argument.
```

And by default it is valid to include @, -, and . in the args part of the url.

But when I do `URL(args="@an-argument.")`, the args string is escaped, creating

```
http://example.com/app/controller/%40an-argument.
```

Is there any way to tell the URL function not to escape the at sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `URL(args="@an-argument.", url_encode=False)`. However, note that if you add a query string, its values will not be encoded either.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way, I think that's url_encode=False, now I look into it (not url_escape).

Comment: Oops. It's fixed now.